# How can I deploy a codeigniter app on an amazon ec2 server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, codeigniter, amazon-ec2, deployment

I am doing an internship in an university and i had to create a blog app with codeigniter. The app is completed and I now need to deploy it on an AWS EC2 server. I am using Putty and xampp. So i have followed this tutorial : https://www.9lessons.info/2015/12/amazon-ec2-setup-with-ubuntu-and-xampp.htmlurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.9lessons.info%2F2015%2F12%2Famazon-ec2-setup-with-ubuntu-and-xampp.html 
But i can't acces to ip-adress/phpmyadmin. I don't know why and I don't know if i am using the best way to deploy my app. If someone could help me it would be very nice !

Comment: Oh i forgot, it seems that there is another application connected to port 80, but i have changed the port to 8080 and it's still not working

Comment: Did you add inbound rule with port 8080 in a security group in which the server is?